# How it is possible rotate a part of 3D tikz picture (like picture) and the bottom area is fix(no rotation)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to rotate picture using 3D tikz like below picture. Is it possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}‎‎
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,10) node[below left]{$z$};
\draw[ultra thick] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4] -- 
    ++(0,0,8.5) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4]--cycle;‎‎
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,8.5) --++(4,0,0) --cycle;‎
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,8.5) --++(0,4,0) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The rotation you show doesn't look to be around the x-axis...

Comment: Or it shall be around x but is drawn incorrectly! I'll adjust my answer!

Comment: Shoot. I forgot it would close it immediately if I nominated the thing as a duplicate....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `rotate around x/y/z` options

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}‎‎
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,10) node[below left]{$z$};
\begin{scope}[rotate around x=20]
\draw[ultra thick] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4] -- 
++(0,0,8.5) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4]--cycle;‎‎
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,8.5) --++(4,0,0) --cycle;‎
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,8.5) --++(0,4,0) --cycle;
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0)--++(0,4,0)node(n1){};
\end{scope}
\draw[dashed,very thick] (0,4,0)--(n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated object]

---

You have to split the paths, if you only want to rotate parts of it. Use the `shift=` key to establish correct rotation of the second arc:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}‎‎
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,10) node[below left]{$z$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate around x=20]‎‎
        \draw[ultra thick] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]node[inner sep=0](n1){};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,8.5)},rotate around x=20]
        \draw[ultra thick] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]node[inner sep=0](n2){};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[ultra thick] (n1.center)--(n2.center)--(0,0,8.5)--(4,0,8.5)--(4,0,0);
    \draw[dashed, very thick](0,4,0)--(n1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

---

The filling of the top area is a bit tricky now, to be honest, because the path is split into several parts. The easiest way of filling would be to concatenate the different paths but I don't know, how to achieve this. Actually, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26627/saving-and-reusing-combining-paths-in-tikz), [Loop Space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space) gives a solution to that task, but I don't know how to use the new syntax of [spath3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3?lang=de).

So my solution is a bit more "quick and dirty", as paths are not closed, which is why the corners are not as nice. However, the top area is filled.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
    %coordinate system
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,10) node[below left]{$z$};

    % draw and save arcs    
    \begin{scope}[rotate around x=20]
        \draw[ultra thick,save path=\arcone] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]node[inner sep=0](n1){};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,8.5)},rotate around x=20]
        \draw[ultra thick,save path=\arctwo] (4,0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]node[inner sep=0](n2){};
    \end{scope}
    % draw and save connecting lines
    \draw[save path=\lineleft,ultra thick](n1.center)--(n2.center);
    \draw[save path=\lineright,ultra thick](4,0,0)--(4,0,8.5);
    % draw additional lines    
    \draw[ultra thick] (n2.center)--(0,0,8.5)--(4,0,8.5);
    \draw[dashed, very thick](0,4,0)--(n1.center);

    % fill the top area:
    \makeatletter
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]% to achieve "inverse" clipping
                \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{\arctwo}
                \clip--(0,0,8.5)--(4,0,8.5) (-10,-10)rectangle(10,10); % any bigger rectangle
                \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{\arcone}
                \fill[red, opacity=0.5]--(n2.center)--(4,0,8.5);
        \end{scope} 
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: filled top area]

Comment: Tank you, but I want rotate like picture, one of area is fix (the bottom area). this kind of deformation is Skew.

Comment: @sayros I adjusted my answer, hope that's what you looking for.

Comment: tank you, this is my answer.

Comment: And how I can fill top area?

Comment: @sayros I'm working on that....

Comment: @sayros, I adjusted my answer, if you like it, you might wish to accept it...

Comment: This code seems to have some embedded `U+200E` marks that cause my pdfLaTeX to reject it

Comment: After (some of) the semicolons